# Pastebin with custom URL

Tags: web-apps, sharing, pastebin

For example this site:

http://pastebin.com/GGeTHNsr

the URL is hard to remember, I would prefer something like this:

http://example.com/custom1

Since my valid answer was deleted, here it is:

http://txti.es

Answer (score 1):

The webapp [rentry.co](https://rentry.co/) does exactly what you are looking for.
[image: Rentry.co screenshot]

It also offers other goodies.
I highly recommend it.

Comment: Would you mind adding a screenshot, including the custom URL field? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use bitly url shortener (you must register to that site).

[image: Bitly screenshot]

[URL shortener homepage](https://bitly.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://www.tiny.cc/ .
You can optionally write a custom URI.

[image: Tiny URL]

Check: http://tiny.cc/axx-example

Comment: Would you mind adding a screenshot, including the custom URL field? Thanks!